# pgsql2shp - Export several part of table

Tags: postgresql, cut

On PostgreSQL (and PgAdmin), i have a table which represents certain cities, and a column with 3 modalities.

```
name; modalitie; geometrie
name1; modalitie1; geom
name2; modalitie2; geom
name3; modalitie1; geom
name4; modalitie3; geom
name5; modalitie3; geom
.....
```

I would like to export this table in as many pieces as there are modalities in the column named "modalitie" (ex: "modalitie1.sql", "modalitie2.sql", etc). I was advised to use "pgsql2shp". I managed to export the whole table, but I couldn't cut it into several parts.

```
pgsql2shp -f path\to\shape -u postgres -h localhost -P "0000" DB "select * from cities"
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it is possible!

The same way you get the fraction of data from a table, using a filter with the ** WHERE ** clause.

```
pgsql2shp -f /some/dir/where/you/can/write/output_shapename -h your_host -p 5432 -u aValidUser your_database "SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE aColumn='anExistsValue'"
```

So, using your table as an example.

```
pgsql2shp -f path\to\shape1 -u postgres -h localhost -P "0000" DB "select * from cities where modalitie='modalitie1'"
```